# How to connect from docker-compose to host

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

How can I connect from docker-compose to the host. In the docker-compose there is an nginx and php running and I would like for the php container to connect to a mysql database that is running on the host. the nginx and php containers are connected via a docker-compose network.

Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

networks:
    test:

services:
    nginx:
        some stuff
        networks:
            - test

    php:
        some stuff
        networks:
            - test
            - HOST?????
```

I think in the php application I would then connect to "localhost" and docker connects this the host.

Is this possible? I have read, that it is possible for individual containers to be connected to the host, but don't know if it is possible when docker-compose is used.

Comment: In the connection string from the php container you have to use the IP of your host system. Normally you can ping the host from the container directly. At the networks you need to set nothing more then only the test network.

Comment: Is it like you want to access your containers from the host?

Comment: @uglyCoder no, the other way around

Comment: @tire0011 i have used my public ip address (this should be the host address, right?) but was not able to connect to it from the php container.

how can i ping the host?

Comment: inside the container: apt-get install -y nmap -->
nping IpHere

Comment: @tire0011 thanks for the help. the command does not work as you wrote it, or do you mean: nping iphere.com?

Comment: only nping 192.168.123.123  --> if not working then you can not reach the host

Comment: can you share the final solution? you can answer your question...

Comment: @tire0011 sadly it did not work. maybe it is just not possible to connect to the host from docker-compose

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Comment: @tire0011 i was talking about docker compose